# Hit sasl_decode error while sending mail through sendmail server

Tags: linux, perl, smtp, sendmail

Having installed sendmail and openwebmail on RHEL workstation 6.3, I can send email through webmail(cgi-bin/openwebmail/openwebmail.pl), but failed to interact with sendmail server in Perl script as following:

```
use Net::SMTP;

my $smtpserver = 'mail.server.com';
my $smtpport = 25;
my $smtpuser   = 'test';
my $smtppassword = 'test';
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtpserver, Port=>$smtpport, Timeout => 10, Debug => 1);
die "Could not connect to server!\n" unless $smtp;
$smtp->auth($smtpuser, $smtppassword);
$smtp->mail("Ann");
$smtp->to("hello\@world.com");
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: hello\@world.com\n");
$smtp->quit;
```

While running this Perl script on Windows 7, the output is below:

```
Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(2.31)
Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.64_01)
Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.31)
Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.28)
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 220 mail.server.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4
; Fri, 11 Apr 2014 19:48:30 +0800
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-mail.server.com Hello [9.110.10.236], please
d to meet you
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-SIZE
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-DSN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-ETRN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250-DELIVERBY
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 250 HELP
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)>>> AUTH DIGEST-MD5
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 334 bm9u...
3VnV5VXB6MlBJeHY5TVE9IixyZWFsbT0iaHV...
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)>>> YXV0a...
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 334 cnNwYXV0axODVhOA==
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)>>>
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)<<< 235 2.0.0 OK Authenticated
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2be1e80)>>> MAIL FROM:<hello>
Net::SMTP: Unexpected EOF on command channel at E:\tool\smtp.pl line 35
```

It showed that client got authenticated but didn't received any data after invoking "$smtp->mail()", it seems server closed the connection at this point.

On the server side, there were some error messages written into /var/log/maillog:

```
Apr 11 19:48:30 bill sendmail[16761]: AUTH=server, relay=[9.110.10.6], authid=test, mech=DIGEST-MD5, bits=128
Apr 11 19:48:30 bill sendmail[16761]: AUTH: sasl_decode error=-1
Apr 11 19:48:30 bill sendmail[16761]: s3BBmUQj016761: [9.110.10.236] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN    during connection to MTA
```

maillog showed authentication method is DIGEST-MD5, but it's failed to invoke sasl_decode.

Anyone can give any clue for this problem? Thanks a lot.

PS: my sendmail.mc is pasted at [github](https://gist.github.com/thinkhy/10481941)

Answer (score 1):

Here I made some guess that the old versions is with bugs. Please check this CPAN RT

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=58002

Comment: Joe, you are right. I rewrote a test case using Java, it got the email delivered. Thanks a lot.